# Optimization of profit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I'm using Ruby, but for the purposes of this problem it doesn't really matter.

Let's say I have two different kinds of resources, the quantities of which are denoted by `a` and `b`.  I can allocate `d` new resources, and since `a` and `b` are of equal cost and equal value to production, I can choose to allocate resources in whatever way is most profitable.

This might best be explained like so: `(a + j) * (b + k) = c`, where `j + k = d`.  I want to maximize `c` by the best allocation of resources, with the understanding that the cost of the two different types of resources and their value to production are the same.  All variables are positive integers, with `a` and `b` being greater than 0. Here's my naive brute force method:

```
def max_alloc(a, b, d)
  max_j = 0
  max_k = 0
  max_c = 0
  (0..d).each do |j|
    k = d - j
    c = (a + j) * (b + k)
    if c > max_c
      max_c = c
      max_j = j
      max_k = k
    end
  end
  [max_j, max_k]
end
```

I'm hoping that there's some sort of mathematical or algorithmic "trick" I'm missing that will keep me from having to resort to brute force.

Comment: If this is a linear equation, can you just solve it?

Comment: That would be great, but the system ends up being not very linear.  :)  Assuming a = 3, b = 2, and d = 2, you end up with the system (3 + j) * (2 + k) = c and j + k = d.  The first equation can be reduced to 3k + 2j + jk - c = -6 ... which is not linear.

Comment: Are ```j``` and ```k``` nonnegative?

Comment: Yes ... I will add that to the problem description to make it more obvious.

Comment: Note that there are solvers that can solve these kinds of problems (but larger ones) directly. This would be a MIQP problem (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need an algorithm to do that?
This is a simple maximum/minimum optimization problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now consider the equation

[image]

It is a function of `j`, so let's call it `f(j)`:

[image]

You want to find `j` such that `c = f(j)` is maximum... so you want to study the sign of it's derivative

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you can draw the table of signs

[image]

There you have it! A maximum for

[image]

this means the `j, k` pair you are looking for is

[image]

and for such values you'll have the maximum value of `c`:

[image]

---

### In Ruby

```
def max_alloc(a, b, d)
    j = (-a + b + d) / 2.0
    j = j.round # round to prevent Float, explained at the end of this answer
    if j < 0
        j = 0 # prevent from negative values
    elsif j > d
        j = d # prevent from values greater than d
    end
    [j, d - j]
end
```

Or even shorter

```
def max_alloc(a, b, d)
    j = ((-a + b + d) / 2.0).round
    j = [0, [j, d].min].max # make sure j is in range 0..d
    [j, d - j]
end
```

A one-liner too if you like

```
def max_alloc(a, b, d)
    [[0, [((-a + b + d) / 2.0).round, d].min].max, d - [0, [((-a + b + d) / 2.0).round, d].min].max]
end
```

---

### An in-depth look at the cases `j < 0` and `j > d`

Let's start from the bounds that `j` must satisfy:

[image]

So `j*` is:

[image]

Now, since `f(j)` is **always** a parabola opened downward, the absolute maximum will be it's vertex, so, as discovered before:

[image]

But what if this point is outside the given range for `j`? You'll have to decide wheter to chose `j* = 0, k* = d` or `j* = d, k* = 0`.

Since `f(j)` is strictly increasing for `j < j*` and strictly descreasing for `j > j*`, the closer you get to `j*`, the greater would be `f(j)` value.

Therefore, if `j* > d` the choose `j* = d`, if `j* < 0` then choose `j = 0`.

Here I show some plots just to see this in action:

[image: j* inside the range... nothing to do]

[image: j* < 0... the highest in range is when j = 0]

[image: j* > d... the highest in range is when j = d]

---

### Why `j.round`?

As you just learned `f(j)` is a parabola, and parabolas have an axis of symmetry. If `j*` is an integer, you are done, otherwise for what integer value is `f(j)` maximized? Well... for the integer value closest to the vertex; i.e., `j.round`.

**Note:** If `a, b` and `d` are integers, then `j*` can only be an integer or `xxx.5`. So `f(j)` would be the same for `j.ceil` and `j.floor`... You choose.

Comment: Thanks ... it's been years since my calculus classes in college.  :)
However, I need an integer solution.  Assuming that a = 3, b = 2, and d = 2, assuming I'm using your solution correctly, I'd get j = (2 + 2 - 3) / 2 = 1/2.  I know from brute forcing that there are two maximum solutions for this a, b, and d where c = 12:  j = 0, k = 2 and j = 1, k = 1

Comment: @ArkieCoder Again, I'd choose the easy way... If you get `1/2` then take its *floor* (`0`) and its *ceil* (`1`) and see when `c` is greater. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your solution. Very pretty! I am testing it now.

Comment: Suppose  `a = 2`, `b = 7`, `d = 3`. Then  `max_alloc(2, 7, 3)
 => [4, -1]`, but the variables must be non-negative.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's not a big deal... Just check `j` and if it's negative set it ti `0`. Thanks anyway, I've added it to the code

Comment: "Thanks anyway"? For informing you that your code was incorrect? Moreover, you haven't shown *why* the point `j*` at which the slope is zero is the maximum value of the function. How do we know it's not the minimum value or an inflexion point? Also, you haven't shown *why* the maximum value occurs at `j = 0` if `j* < 0` and at `j = d` if `j* > d`.

Comment: I say *"study the sign of it's derivative"* and that's how you know that `j*` is maximum. The *"Thanks anyway"* was ment as a polite thanks, I apologize for my poor english :) About the second part you are right, I'm updating

Comment: The sign of the derivative is plus for some `j` and minus for others. It's the second derivative you need to examine (which I'm sure you know).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm sorry but this time I have to contradict you. The sign of the first derivative is enough to determine maxmium and minimum of functions.

Comment: If `f(x) = 2 + 6x - x^2`, `f'(x) = 6 - 2x = 0` so the slope is zero at `x = 3`, is positive for `x < 3` and is negative for `x > 3`. So what is the sign of the derivative here? Of interest is whether the derivative is increasing (implies a maximum) or decreasing (a minumum) with `x`, which is equivalent to the second derivative (`f''(x) = -2`) being negative or positive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155032/discussion-between-busy-beaver-and-cary-swoveland).

Answer (score 0):

For given constants `a` and `b`, let

```
f(j,k) = (a + j) * (b + k)
```

We wish to maximize `f(j,k)` subject to three requirements:

- `j + k = d`, for a given constant `d`
- `j >= 0`
- `k >= 0`

We can substitute out `k` (or `j`) to by replacing `k` with

```
k = d - j
```

This changes `f` to:

```
f(j) = (a + j) * (b + d - j)
     = a*(b + d) + (b + d - a)*j -j**2
```

The problem is now to maximize `f` subject to:

```
0 <= j <= d
```

The second part of this inequality follows from `k = d - j >= 0`. If `d = 0`, `j = k = 0` is the only solution that satisfies the requirement that the variables are non-negative. If `d < 0` there is no feasible solution. These two cases should be checked for but I will assume `d > 0`.

We first set the derivative of `f` to zero and solve for `j` to determine where `f`'s slope is zero:

```
f'(j) = b + d - a - 2*j = 0
```

so

```
j* = (b + d - a)/2
```

As the second derivative of `f` is

```
f''(j) = -2 < 0
```

we know `f` is concave, so `j*` is a maximum (rather than a minimum were it convex). Convex and concave functions are shown here<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Convex and Concave Functions]

Consider the graph of the concave function. Values of `j` are on the horizontal axis. Since `j*` must be between `0` and `d` to be feasible (both variables have non-negative values), let the points `a`, `c` and `b` on the graph equal `0`, `j*` and `d`, respectively.

There are three possibilities:

- `0 <= j* <= d`, in which case that is a feasible solution (since `k = d - j* >= 0`).
- `j* < 0`, in which case the largest feasible value of `f` is where `j = 0`.
- `j* > d`, in which case the largest feasible value of `f` is where `j = d`.

Once the optimum value of `j` has been determined, `k = d - j`

Here are some examples.

*Ex. 1: `a = 2`, `b = 3`, `d = 5`*

```
j* = (b + d - a)/2 = (3 + 5 - 2)/2 = 3
```

Since `0 <= 3 <= 5`, `j = 3`, `k = 5 - 3 = 2` are the optimum values of `j` and `k` and `f(3) = 25` is the optimum value.

*Ex. 2: `a = 6`, `b = 1`, `d = 3`*

```
j* = (b + d - a)/2 = (1 + 3 - 6)/2 = -1
```

Since `-1 < 0`, `j = 0`, `k = 3 - 0 = 3` are the optimum values of `j` and `k` and `f(0) = 24` is the optimum value.

*Ex. 3: `a = 2`, `b = 7`, `d = 3`*

```
j* = (b + d - a)/2 = (7 + 3 - 2)/2 = 4
```

Since `4 < 3`, `j = 3`, `k = 3 - 3 = 0` is the optimum value of `j` and `f(3) = 35` is the optimum value.

If `j` and `k` must be integer-valued at the maximum value of `f`, we can assume `a`, `b` and `d` are integer-valued. (If `a` and `b` are not, `a` can be rounded up and `b` rounded down.) Let `j*` now be the value of `j` satisfying `0 <= j <= d` for which is `f(j)` is a maximum (but `j*` is not necessarily an integer). Because `f` is concave, if `j*` is not integer, the optimal value of `j` is `J*.floor` if `f(j*.floor) >= f(j*.ceil)` and `j*.ceil` otherwise.

<sup>1 A function `f` is concave if, for all `a` and `b`, `a < b`, and all `x`, `a <= x <= b`, `f(x) >= g(x)`, where `g` is the linear function having the property that `g(a) = f(a)` and `g(b) = f(b)`.</sup>